# Label for the group bar color

Tags: flutter, dart, graph

I follow this [link](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/grouped_fill_color.html) to make a group bar chart. Does it has a properties to show the label for each color? I want to display the label on the right hand side.

I can't found the answer.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is defined in the chart's behaviors:

[image]

```
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new charts.BarChart(
    seriesList,
    animate: animate,
    defaultRenderer: new charts.BarRendererConfig(
        groupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.grouped, strokeWidthPx: 2.0),
    behaviors: [
      charts.SeriesLegend(
        position: charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
        horizontalFirst: true,
        cellPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, bottom: 4.0),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks. Can I make the label displayed in two lines ? I have 5 items and the text kinda long

Comment: Yes, with `horizontalFirst: false` and `desiredMaxRows: 2`. Have a look here for the API: https://pub.dev/documentation/charts_flutter/latest/flutter/ChartBehavior-class.html and here for an example: https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/legends/series_legend_options